# Jinput getAray not retrieving RAW details from codemirror editor in Joomla 4

Tags: joomla-4.x, joomla-api

I am busy with a project to convert an Joomla 3 template to Joomla 4. The Jinput is not giving me RAW data it is removing the script tags from my inputs. I worked through a couple of similar problems on the web still could not get it right.

The XML for the field is

```
<field name="fieldname" type="editor" default="&lt;script&gt; &lt;/script&gt;" label="Add code to the top &lt; head &gt;" description="" rows="10" cols="5" filter="raw" editor="codemirror|none"/>
```

The input code is

```
$app    = JFactory::getApplication();
$input  = $app->input;
$post   = $input->post->getArray();
```

I am getting the values in the following foreach loop

```
foreach (array_keys($post['jform']['params']) as $param) {
  $value = $post['jform']['params'][$param];
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the filter because otherwise default filter is applied. There are several ways to do it. First one is to pass the third argument to `getArray()`:

```
$post = $input->post->getArray([], null, 'RAW');
```

This isn't recommended because `Joomla\CMS\Input\Input` is deprecated and `getArray()` method in replacement `Joomla\Input\Input` class does not have a third argument.

Another way is to specify data/filter pairs:

```
$post = $input->post->getArray(['jform' => 'ARRAY', 'task' => 'CMD']);
```

This method also allows defining nested fields/filters within data arrays:

```
$post = $input->post->getArray(['jform' => ['title' => 'STRING', 'articletext' => 'RAW']]);
```

If you need just a single top level data array like `jform`, simplest way is to use `get()` method instead:

```
$post = $input->post->get('jform', [], 'ARRAY');
```