# Input JSON strips HTML

Tags: joomla-4.x, jinput, json

I have successfully developed a Joomla 4 API which receives JSON data containing HTML to update the database. - The HTML markup is stripped away when using this code:

```
$input = $this->input->json->get('data', null, 'json');
$data = json_decode(json_encode($input), false);
```

How can I make sure the HTML markup stays intact?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `json` filter which causes default filter to be applied, stripping away HTML. Use a different filter. [This answer](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/33214/12652) shows some examples. Using `array` filter should work:

```
$input = $this->input->json->get('data', [], 'array');
```

Specifically for JSON there is `Joomla\Input\Json::getRaw()` method which returns the raw JSON string:

```
$input = $this->input->json->getRaw();
$data = json_decode($input, false);
```

But be aware it doesn't take manipulations done on the input object into account, data may be outdated.

Comment: Thanks for the hint with the array. I cast it into an object ```$data = (object) $input;``` to get the expected result. Awesome!